# Chrome Extension is not working - OnClick/addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I want to have a Chrome Extension that changes when a button is clicked. However, it does not work.

This is the HTML Code which I want to alternate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <input type="text" id="myText" value="Notes...">
        <button type="button" id="copyNote">Save Note</button>
        <div id="Notes">ssss</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following javascript is supposed to change the HTML:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var copyNote = document.getElementById('copyNote');
    // onClick's logic below:
    copyNote.addEventListener('click', function() {
        saveNote;
    });
});

function saveNote(){
    var Note1 = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("Notes").innerHTML = "xxxxxxx"; 
}
```

Comment: You forgot the parentheses when you try to call saveNode, try: `saveNote()`